# Exporting jasmine test results in json format from grunt

Tags: json, gruntjs, jasmine

I am using Jasmine to execute the tests from the Grunt task. I want to output the results from the test cases in JSON. Below is the configuration for the jasmine. This configuration generates XML files under junit folder.

```
var conf = {

        src: [
           // '../../../Test.UnitTest.JS/UnitTests/' + name + '/**/*.js'
        ],
        options: {
            template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
            templateOptions: {
                requireConfig: {
                    baseUrl: 'SinglePageApplications/' + name,
                    //waitSeconds: 30,
                    paths: mixIn({
                        'knockout-editables': '../../Assets/scripts/vendor/ko.editables-0.9.0',
                        'knockout-validation': '../../Assets/scripts/vendor/knockout.validation-1.0.2',
                        'bignumber': '../../Assets/scripts/vendor/bignumber-1.4.1',
                        'testutils': '../../../Test.UnitTest.JS/Utils',
                        'shared': '../../Legacy/Shared',
                        'testdata': '../../../Test.UnitTest.JS/UnitTests/' + name + '/testdata' 
                    }, addConfigurationPaths(app))

                }
            },
            helpers: [
                'Assets/scripts/ato/helperscript.js'
            ],
            specs: [
                       '../Test.UnitTest.JS/UnitTests/' + name + '/**/*.js'
            ],
            junit: {
                path: 'build/junit/' + name + '/'
            },
            timeout: 100000,
            vendor: arr
        }
            ,
        //specs : 'src/test/js/unit-headless.html',

        phantomjs: {
            'ignore-ssl-errors': true
        }
 }
```

I want the results to be displayed in JSON format so I installed jasmine-json-test-reporter using npm and tried implemented it in my current config like this:

```
 var conf = {

        src: [
           // '../../../Test.UnitTest.JS/UnitTests/' + name + '/**/*.js'
        ],
        options: {
            template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
            templateOptions: {
                requireConfig: {
                    baseUrl: 'SinglePageApplications/' + name,
                    //waitSeconds: 30,
                    paths: mixIn({
                        'knockout-editables': '../../Assets/scripts/vendor/ko.editables-0.9.0',
                        'knockout-validation': '../../Assets/scripts/vendor/knockout.validation-1.0.2',
                        'bignumber': '../../Assets/scripts/vendor/bignumber-1.4.1',
                        'testutils': '../../../Test.UnitTest.JS/Utils',
                        'shared': '../../Legacy/Shared',
                        'testdata': '../../../Test.UnitTest.JS/UnitTests/' + name + '/testdata' 
                    }, addConfigurationPaths(app))

                }
            },
            helpers: [
                'Assets/scripts/ato/helperscript.js'

                //'Legacy/Shared/common/constants.js'
            ],
            specs: [
                //'../Test.UnitTest.JS/UnitTests/' + name + '/common/*.js',
                //'../Test.UnitTest.JS/UnitTests/' + name + '/testdata',
                '../Test.UnitTest.JS/UnitTests/' + name + '/**/*.js'
            ],
            junit: {
                path: 'build/junit/' + name + '/'
            },
            timeout: 100000,
            vendor: arr
        }
            ,
        //specs : 'src/test/js/unit-headless.html',

        phantomjs: {
            'ignore-ssl-errors': true
        },
        onPrepare: function () {
            var JSONReporter = require('jasmine-json-test-reporter');
            var jasmine = require('jasmine');
            return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) {
                browser.params['browsername'] = config.capabilities.browserName.toUpperCase();
                browser.params['version'] = config.capabilities.version || 'latest stable';
                browser.params['platform'] = config.capabilities.os + '-' + config.capabilities.os_version;
                jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new JSONReporter({
                    file: 'results/' + browser.params.platform + '-' + browser.params.version + '.' + browser.params.browsername + '.json',
                    beautify: true,
                    indentationLevel: 2 // used if beautify === true 
                }));
            });
        }

    }
```

This code is not generating any json file. I am not too sure use jasmine-json-test-reporter with current jasmine config.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get it working. The source files were not point to the right locations. Changing the following lines fixed it:

```
src: [
                'SinglePageApplications/' + name + '/common/**/*.js',
                'SinglePageApplications/' + name + '/viewmodels/**/*.js',
                'SinglePageApplications/' + name + '/views/**/*.js',
                'SinglePageApplications/' + name + '/main.js'
            ],
```